# Images in app/public (laravel) not show in Heroku app

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, amazon-s3, file-storage

I have a project in Laravel in which one of the sections uploads images to the server. Images are saved by using File storage and in the / storage/app/public folder.

In local it works correctly and the images look good, but when I upload the project to Heroku, the images are not seen. Even in Heroku if I run this command there are issues:

```
php artisan storage: link
```

Why is it that the images are not visible? I would not want to use AWS S3 for this. What could I have missed?

Comment: What are the broken images linking to, and what are they supposed to link to?

Comment: Images are displayed with Storage :: url ('file1.jpg'); (http://site.dev/file1.jpg) Because the images are stored in / storage / app / public, this way the content is not visible to the users, only when it is needed. But for some reason in heroku this does not happen, but in local everything works correctly.

Comment: What is the permission of storage folder. This could be the issue.

Comment: "I would not want to use AWS S3 for this." Well, you might have to. If not S3, some other file storage service. [Heroku's filesystem is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem); any files you store there will be lost the next time your Dyno restarts. This happens quite frequently (at least once per day).

Comment: "Even in heroku run the command "php artisan storage: link"" That's not working, because when you use `heroku run` you're connecting to a *new, **separate** instance* from what's running on the web.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Heroku doesn't have file storage. So if you're going to use it for your servers you need to figure out another way to store files.

Comment: Yep, this is the only answer when it comes to Heroku. You simply can't store files locally on Heroku - dynos restart at least once daily, and you'll lose every single file uploaded to them each time. Something like S3 or storing files in the database is **required** there for any files not in version control.

Answer (score 9):

In your composer.json add:

"post-install-cmd": [
    "ln -sr storage/app/public public/storage"
],

Comment: This works!!! Please can you explain what it is actually doing ?

Comment: Worked just fine.
Actually it makes the link realtime when the project gets deployed everytime by heroku

Comment: this answer need to be more explain

Answer (score 1):

What I did that worked for me:

In your composer.json add:

`"post-install-cmd": [ "ln -sr storage/app/public public/storage" ],`( don't forget the comma `,` if you have any other line after the command above) But you should add the line above in scripts section.

Comment: This same answer was already given [4 years prior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46860478/1255289).

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can upload images to the public folder instead using of a storage folder, by this method you will not get problems like the above.
for that, you need to change the config in `app/filesystem.php`

Change from:

```
'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

Change into:

```
'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path(),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/public',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

And you can store files so:

```
$pathToFile = Storage::disk('public')->put('uploads/', $file);
```

Now you can insert `$pathToFile` variable to the Database!

Answer (score -1):

Also, you need to run the command:

```
 php artisan storage:link
```

Before running this command please check if the storage folder is already there or not inside the public folder if it's there then rename it to storage-bk and run the command. This way it creates new shortcut folder storage (storage/app/public).

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:
You can add to your command line in your Procfile.
`worker: php artisan storage:link`

After adding this please push your project to Heroku again.

[image: worker: php artisan storage:link]